# Ionic 3 - Don't change home button to back button in navbar

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have something like that:

In my navbar I have a home button for toggling the menu.

The problem is, ionic automatically changes it from home button into back button when the nav stack has more than 1 page.

**I need the button to always remain a home button that toggles the menu, regardless of how many pages there are in the nav stack.**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>

        <button ion-button menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
        </button>

    <ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

Solutions that are not good for my case:

1) It doesn't happen if I use "setRoot" instead of "push" when changing pages, because then the nav stack always has 1 page.

However this is not an option for me, I'd like to keep using "push" and have the button remain a home button that toggles menu, instead of changing into a back button that goes back 1 page.

2) Setting hideBackButton="false" completely hides the back button, but it doesn't mean that the home button is shown instead, neither is shown.

```
<ion-navbar hideBackButton="false">
```

Comment: Try to use `ion-toolbar` instead of `ion-navbar`

Comment: What you could do is in the navigation always use `setRoot()` instead of `push()` which will prevent a nav stack from forming and therefor the back will never show

Comment: a question for you. If you have to use "push", how are you going to go / how do you want to go back to the previous pages?

Comment: @Duannx - works thanks, didn't test on device yet though. Are there any known downsides to using ion-toolbar instead of ion-navbar.
arkade - I get the feeling you didn't read everything I wrote.
CharlieNg - I have a fixed back button in the header near the home button, I only wrote here part of the code.

Comment: Try adding `enable-menu-with-back-views="true"` property to `ion-side-menus`

Comment: @RoyiBernthal: i do not find any downsides so far.

Comment: Swapnil did you mean ion-menu? @Duannx I understand, good. Feel free to write an official answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @RoyiBernthal: I post an answer. It would be nice if you accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ion-toolbar instead of ion-navbar:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    <ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Though is works it doesn't replace the back button on Android since the toolbar only aligns icons to the right in Android